# Error releasing APK on Android Studio with pre-existing keystore

Tags: android, key, release, keystore

I had an old app on Eclipse which I released with a signed with a key created with Eclipse (a new keystore) which worked fine. Then i imported my project on Android Studio for a big update but when I try to generate a release APK with the keystore created before in Eclipse it fails and gives me this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> Failed to read key app from store "D:\Developer stuff\Keystores\KEYSTORE": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

In Eclipse it works fine (i tried it today) and my keystore password and alias password are correct, so i don't know what to do now, i really need to update my existing app with this keystore. Please help me, thanks in advance.